# How can solve this matrix problem?

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

The determinant for the matrix is 16

[image]

Comment: So? What have you tried so far? And, honestly, I don't like your nick at all!

Comment: Tried using the adjoint form to find the inverse matrix and solve it with x=A^-1*b, but that would get me back a zero column matrix. I don't know any other methods that won't get me back a zero matrix :( @FriedrichPhilipp

Comment: You don't need to compute the inverse matrix. What is $b$ here?

Comment: b is zero column matrix, is the only solution the trivial solution? @FriedrichPhilipp

Comment: Yes, indeed,since $A^{-1}0=0$.

Comment: oh yea... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since the determinant is positive, how many solution do you think there are?

Comment: I only know that if the det is 0 than there may be infinite or no solutions, So positive det would mean a unique solution then what does negative det mean?. omm also since the det is positive that means there are no zeros in the diagonal when in reduced row echolon form. so the only solution is the trivial right?

Comment: non-zero determinant means unique solution.

Comment: so x =0, y =0, z =0 since there are no free variables. as the unique solution?

Comment: yes, congratulations.